Movie like underworld, +10 years ago, man with HUGE retractable blade
I am trying to find the name of a movie like Underworld, watched over 10 years ago, with a man with HUGE retractable blade. The man seems old, east european / slav, and he started to cut a car with a huge blade, but gets stuck. The blade seemed telescopic, was huge, and came from his clothes below the arm but with the movement of the arm. It resembled that tool that Batman (Returns?) uses to cut a piece of a car and get stuck but much larger.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.   Where did you see this movie?  Where did the blade retract?  Did it telescope into his hand or fold out of his arm?  Or another body part?  Why was he trying to cut a car?

Tv, it seems something telescopic, huge, that came from his clothes below the arm but with the movement of the arm. Resembles that tool that Batman (returns?) uses to cut a piece of a car and get stuck but much larger

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BladeBelowTheShoulder was my first thought. I don't see anything there that matches, but you might see if a name looks familiar.

You mention Underworld. Were there werewolves? Vampires? Other creatures?

And... are you certain it isn't Underworld? Lucian does have a blade that telescopes from his arm.

Re: FuzzyBoots comment -- take a look and see if this looks familiar:
https://underworld.fandom.com/wiki/Knives?file=Lucianwrist.jpg

@K-H-W: Thank you for the image. I wasn't on a computer where I could do that search at the time.

How was the character cutting the car?  Cutting it in two?  Cutting it open to get inside? From the front, side or top?

Is it possible that you're actually thinking of Underworld and Lucian's arm blade?


Lucian wields a spring-mounted blade hidden under the right sleeve of his jacket in Underworld. The blade is first seen when Lucian jumps onto the hood of Selene's car and stabs her through her shoulder, severing an artery and almost killing her.
He later uses the knife again to stab Kraven, so that Kraven would be distracted long enough for Selene to bite Michael Corvin, thus making Michael a Lycan-Vampire Hybrid and assuring that Lucian's vision for revenge was complete.

Lucian stabbing the car roof with his blade (2:50 in)




Not an exact match, but are you perhaps thinking of Night Watch (2004)? The main antagonist of the movie, Zavulon, used his spine as a sword during the climax of the movie. See below:
                                                   

Does it retract into his arm?  Does he slice a car with it?

The main antagonist of the movie used his- what? what????????
